# Symfony2 mapping_types

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2.0 and add mapping_types in config.yml

```
doctrine:
        dbal:
            default_connection: default
            connections:
                default:
                    driver:   pdo_mysql
                    host:     localhost
                    dbname:   work_contactbee
                    user:     devuser
                    password: devuser
                    mapping_types:
                        enum: string
```

But when I try to update schema: **php app/console doctrine:schema:update**
I get an exeption ***Unrecognized options "mapping_types" under "doctrine.dbal.connections.default***

Anybody can help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone still looking. I solved this for my situation by removing the `connections` and `default_connections` part.

So:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     localhost
        dbname:   work_contactbee
        user:     devuser
        password: devuser
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
```

Either the docs are wrong, or (more likely) I've misinterpreted them. I'm not sure why your example didn't work tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Symfony are you using? From 2.1 the mapping_types are defined as an array of mapping_types so if you are using the latest version (2.2), enum: string is no longer valid. See full list of config options for latest version: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: I'm using 2.0 and I have to use it with no option for update.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't noticed you had said the version number in the question. My apologies, this was a poor answer to your question.